# how to pass a dictionary holding a list of minutes through qpython to kdb

Tags: python, kdb

I'm trying to query a specific function through qpython. the function expects a dictionary with several arguments, the first one being a date (type -14), the second one being a list of minutes (type 17).

I wrote this little example which hopefully illustrates faithfully the issue:

```
\d .test

testfun:{[args]
    
    one:args[`one];
    two:args[`two];
    
    ' string type args[`two];
    :42;
    };
```

now when I query through qpython:

```
from qpython import qconnection
from qpython.qcollection import QDictionary, qlist
import numpy as np
from qpython.qtype import QLONG_LIST, QSYMBOL_LIST, QMINUTE_LIST


query='{[arg_dict] :.test.testfun[arg_dict] }'

kdbconfig = {
        'q_host': 'q_host',
        'q_port': 42,
        'q_usr': 'q_usr',
        'q_pwd': 'q_pwd' 
        }

params = {
    "one" : np.datetime64('2021-01-06', 'D'),
    "two" : qlist([ np.timedelta64(10*60, 'm'), np.timedelta64(10*60+30, 'm')] , qtype = QMINUTE_LIST)
    }

qparams = QDictionary(list(params.keys()), list(params.values()))


with qconnection.QConnection(host=kdbconfig['q_host'],
                                     port=kdbconfig['q_port'],
                                     username=kdbconfig['q_usr'],
                                     password=kdbconfig['q_pwd'] ) as q:
        data = q.sendSync(query, qparams, pandas = True)
        if data is None:
            raise ValueError("didnt return any data")
```

but I get `QException: b'-14'` while I would expect type 17
`qparams.values` is worth: `[numpy.datetime64('2021-01-06'), QList([420, 450], dtype='timedelta64[m]')]`
so it looks reasonable to me.

Anyone would have an idea how to make this work please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys are being sent as strings not symbols:

```
q).debug
"one"| 2021.01.06
"two"| 10:00 10:30

q).debug[`two]
0Nd
q)type .debug[`two]
-14h
```

`two is returning a null according to the type of the first item in the dictionary. I'm not actually sure how qpython handles strings vs symbols but you could update the q function to this:

```
.test.testfun:{[args]
  one:args["one"];
  two:args["two"];
  string type args["two"]
  };
```

Edit: How to debug

If the query is sending to the q process ok, it is best to debug on the kdb side if it is not acting as expected. I defined the test q function as:

```
.test.testfun:{[args].debug:args;};
```

This allowed me to view what kdb was receiving. Nice one on the `np.string_`, this defines it as symbols:

```
qparams = QDictionary(np.string_(list(params.keys())), list(params.values()))

q).debug
one| 2021.01.06
two| 10:00 10:30
```

You could also define the q function as follows so it returns to python:

```
// .Q.s1 returns the string representation of an object
q).test.testfun:{[args].debug:args;.Q.s1 .debug};

python test.py
b'`one`two!(2021.01.06;10:00 10:30)'
```

My Script:

```
from qpython import qconnection
from qpython.qcollection import QDictionary, qlist
import numpy as np
from qpython.qtype import QLONG_LIST, QSYMBOL_LIST, QMINUTE_LIST


query='{[arg_dict] :.test.testfun[arg_dict] }'

params = {
    "one" : np.datetime64('2021-01-06', 'D'),
    "two" : qlist([ np.timedelta64(10*60, 'm'), np.timedelta64(10*60+30, 'm')] , qtype = QMINUTE_LIST)
    }

qparams = QDictionary(np.string_(list(params.keys())), list(params.values()))

with qconnection.QConnection(host="localhost",
                                     port=12345,
                                     username="",
                                     password="" ) as q:
        data = q.sendSync(query, qparams)
        if data is None:
            raise ValueError("didnt return any data")
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! sym are represented with numpy.string_ ill test tomorrow but would makes sense. But how did you get the value of the dict? Currently im using the exception to send back values to the python process from my analyst which is not ideal...

Comment: that was it. thank you for the detailed explanation, it will be very  useful!